# Notification "not enough system space" appears when using Internet in Vivo Y15

Tags: insufficient-memory

When I surf the internet in my Vivo Y15 I see a  notification "not enough system space". I cleaned the cache and system trash in my phone, but the notification still appears.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: For a starter, you might wish to take a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which contains some first-aid on similar cases. Though your case could be a bit different if you really quoted the error message *literally* – never saw it phrased like this. If it *is* the literal notification text, follow [Arielle's advice](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113567/16575) – but please let us know what app it was for potential further advice.

Answer (score 0):

The notification doesn't sound like something that would appear on stock Android firmware. Hold down on the notification, then if there's an option called "Ignore messages like this", select it. If there isn't, choose "App Info" and uncheck the box labelled "Show notifications".